# Restricting EC2 instance to have read Only Access to ECR repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

I have created ecr repository to store docker images. I want to see if i can only provide read-only access to ec2 instance . My ec2 instance has been given a role which comprise of the perimssion : AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly  which can be seens as --

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]

  }
```

My ecr policy reads like:

```
 {
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ecr repo policy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::531523267983:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But when i am trying to push a docker image from my ec2 instance to this repository , i am successfully able to push that , even though i have provided readonly access to my ec2 instance. Where am i going wrong

Comment: http://blog.shippable.com/setting-permissions-on-aws-ec2-ecr-repositories. 
usr3 should have permissions to just pull images from repo 2. Try usr3 policy and tell us if it works for you . 

 FYI : "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken" is not part of "Action".

Comment: @AasthaJain i am logging in to ec2 instance with ec2-user. What i want is the ec2 instance should be restricted to push images on ECR .Am not considering the user here . Is there a way we can restrict the resource from using ec2 rather than the user?